# ensuring a minimum number of rows returned

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am making a simple message board in PHP with a MySQL database. I have limited messages to 20 a page with the 'LIMIT' operation.

An example of my URL is: `http://www.example.com/?page=1`

If page is not specified, it defaults to 1. As I mentioned earlier, there is a limit of 20 per page, however if that is out of a possible 30 and I wish to view page 2, I only end up with 10 results. In this case, the LIMIT part of my query resembles `LIMIT 20,40` - How can I ensure in this case that 20 are returned?

I would prefer to try and keep this as much on the MySQL side as possible.

**EDIT:**
To clarify, if I am on page 2, I will be fetching rows 20-30, however this is only 10 rows, so I wish to select 10-30 instead.

**EDIT:**
I am currently using the following query:

My query:

```
SELECT MOD(COUNT(`ID`),20) AS lmt WHERE `threadID`=2;
SELECT * FROM `msg_messages` WHERE `threadID`=2 LIMIT 20-(20-lmt) , 40-(20-lmt) ;
```

There are 30 records this matches.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to do this? It is non-standard and to be honest it sounds terribly confusing. Why do you need this?

Comment: Could you reverse the order and take the first 20 instead?

Comment: in link pass start and end parameter `http://www.example.com/?page=1,start=20,end=40`

Comment: If I'm understanding the question, you basically want to page from the _end_ of your results instead of the _beginning_? So if you have 30 total results, with 20 per page, page 1 would have 10 results and page 2 would have 20 results? The question could be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to really understand the question, but if I do I think that the best practive would be to prevent users to go to a page with no results. To do so, you can easily check how many rows you have in total even if you are using the "LIMIT" clause using [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html).

For example you could do:

```
Select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from blog_posts where balblabla...
```

Then you have to run another query like this:

```
Select FOUND_ROWS() as posts_count
```

It will return the total rows very quickly. With this result and knowing the current page, you can decide if you display next/prev links to the user.

Comment: Simon, I tried what you suggested, however I was only getting the results of the first query returned?

Comment: You have to run another query with "Select FOUND_ROWS() as posts_count" to get the total number of rows, did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I can get the number of rows using Alex's reply, however I can not then use the return value to get any results.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/20 AS pages FROM tbl;
```

..to get the max number of pages, then work out if you're going to be left with a partial set and adjust your paging query accordingly.